# Laravel: Set path of view after initializing it

Tags: view, laravel-5

Laravel 5. I want to set path of the view later. But create an instance so that I can set data to it.

So in the result:

```
$view = new View();
$view->with('key', $data);
$view->setPath($path);
$view->render();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Because the `Illuminate\View\View` constructor requires the `view path` as  parameter.

Comment: I think it is the situation when laravel becomes not so flexible. As I see from this and other examples it is better to create a constructor without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

One way to it is to create a simple custom class `View`. The content of it will be:

```
public function __construct($data = null) {
    if ($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}

public function with($key, $val) {
    if (is_array($key)) {
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $key);
    } else {
        $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }
}

public function setPath($path) {
    $this->path = $path;
}

public function render() {
    return view($this->path, $this->data);
}
```

It allows to manage the flow of view.